# How can I access ForeignKey model attributes in Angular using serialized data from Django

Tags: django, angular, serialization

I am using Angular 8 and Django 3. I want to create a page for a `Restaurant` that shows all of the `Recipes` that the `Restaurant` has. I have a `Restaurant` model and a `Recipe` model with `ForeignKey` relation as follows:

**EDIT:**
**models.py**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='recipe', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am serializing the data for the `Restaurant` using a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`:

**serializers.py**

```
class RestaurantDetail(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recipe = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'food', 'recipe')
```

When I put in the url (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurants/restaurantdetail/2`) in Postman I get the correct response data because it is giving me the name of the `Restaurant` as well as an array of `Recipe` `pk` values that are related to the `Restaurant`. So I am serializing correctly.

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "sec",
    "recipe": [
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

What I want to do however, is in my Angular `html` file be able to access the name of each `Recipe` in the array. All I can access is the `pk` value when I loop over the array. Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to create another Angular component that goes and looks up and returns a new `Recipe` object for each `pk` value.

In other words I guess the serializer is not returning a `Recipe` object but simply its `pk` value?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using nested Serialization. This is a good link to the docs [Nested Serialization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

**serializers.py**

```
class RecipeShort(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id','name')


class RestaurantDetail(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recipe = RecipeShort(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'food', 'recipe')
```